# Using queries to retrieve data from connected tables

Tags: mysql, sql

#### What I want to do:

I would like to retrieve all data fields about a `Customer`(including all data from tables that are related with him (e.g the data fields of the `Country` & data fields of the `referralagent`

I'd like my query to take as a parameter the `idUser`.

---

**Here is my EER Diagram:**

[image: EER Diagram]

---

**What I tried:**

```
SELECT
referralagent.firstName
,referralagent.lastName
,customer.firstName
,customer.lastName
,customer.address
,customer.postcode
,customer.profession
,customer.phoneNumWork
,customer.phoneNumMobile
,customer.phoneNumHome
,country.name
,nationality.name

    FROM 
        customer
        INNER JOIN referralagent
            ON customer.ReferralAgent_idreferralAgent = referralagent.idReferralAgent
        INNER JOIN country
            ON customer.countryResidence = country.idCountry
        INNER JOIN nationality
            ON customer.nationality = nationality.idNationality

            WHERE customer.idUser = '7'
```

**The question:**

I'm not confident that what I tried is something that's "correct". Is there
any better way to do it?

Comment: Are you missing data? Running slow? Any problems at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is basically correct, I just edited the `SELECT` part so it is a bit shorter.

```
SELECT customer.*, referralagent.firstName,
       referralagent.lastName, country.name, nationality.name
FROM   customer, country, nationality, referralagent
       INNER JOIN referralagent
             ON customer.ReferralAgent_idreferralAgent = referralagent.idReferralAgent
       INNER JOIN country
             ON customer.countryResidence = country.idCountry
       INNER JOIN nationality
             ON customer.nationality = nationality.idNationality
```

Typing just a `*` returns every column. Typing `table_name.*` returns every column of a certain table.

The JOINS are correct you merge the tables with the given conditions:

`customer.ReferralAgent_idreferralAgent = referralagent.idReferralAgent`

`customer.countryResidence = country.idCountry`

`customer.nationality = nationality.idNationality`